# Verificação de servidor php

Tags: php

Estou com uma situação aqui em que preciso identificar o servidor em que o site está situado. Tem como verificar se um servidor é windows ou Linux através do código php?

Comment: `phpinfo();` não te mostra?

Comment: Não cheguei a ver Diego Felipe, vou verificar

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Para isso, o PHP tem uma função nativa, e uma constante:

```
echo php_uname();  // Sistema em execução no momento
echo PHP_OS;       // Sistema usado para BUILD do PHP
```

Veja o formato do retorno:

```
php_uname()                                                       PHP_OS    php-uname('s')
Linux localhost 2.4.21-0.13 #1 Fri Mar 14 15:08:06 EST 2003 i686  Linux     Linux
FreeBSD localhost 3.2-RELEASE #15: Mon Dec 17 08:46:02 GMT 2001   FreeBSD   FreeBSD
Windows NT XN1 5.1 build 2600                                     WINNT     Windows NT
```

Só que tem um cuidado a ser tomado: o `PHP_OS` retorna qual foi o sistema operacional onde foi feito o ***build*** do PHP, e não necessariamente onde está sendo executado.

Claro que normalmente as duas coisas coincidem, mas saber a diferença é importante na hora em que a coisa não funciona como estamos esperando.

A sugestão seria este caminho:

```
$isWindows = stristr( php_uname( 's' ), 'Windows' );
```

### Parâmetros de modo do `php_uname()`:

- `a` (default) Retorna na sequência os ítens `s`, `n`, `r`, `v` e `m`;
- `s` nome do OS. ex: `FreeBSD`;
- `n` nome do Host. ex: `localhost.example.com`;
- `r` nome do release. ex: `5.1.2-RELEASE`;
- `v` versão (varia um bocado);
- `m` tipo de máquina. ex: `i386`.

Veja funcionando no **[IDEONE](http://ideone.com/FkCqlz)**.

Comment: Resposta esclarecedora! Funcionou tudo certinho! Vlw!

Answer (score 1):

```
if (stripos(php_uname('s'), 'win') === 0) {
    echo 'windows';
} else {
    echo 'other, probably *unix family';
}
```

ou

```
if (DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR == '\\') {
    echo 'windows';
} else {
    echo 'other, probably *unix family';
}
```

O primeiro modo pode gerar inconsistência caso apareça um sistema linux cujo nome comece com "win". Já pensou em "Winux Operating System"? Pode acontecer, mas é algo difícil.

O segundo modo é mais rápido porém, no futuro pode tornar-se inconsistente. Por exemplo, pode ser que o Windows modifique o separador de diretório para barra normal `/` ou sistemas linux podem passar a usar barra invertida `\`. Apesar de ser uma possibilidade muito remota para ambos os casos.

Particularmente, eu utilizo a verificação do `DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR`.

Comment: Se ao inves de se verificar se é windows, checar se é unix, nao reduz a margem de erro do primeiro método?

Comment: Dá na mesma e ainda terá uma dificuldade maior em encontrar um identificador comum para "linux" ou "unix". O problema é que linux tem diversas distribuições. E muitas das quais não incluem o termo "linux" ou "unix" no nome exibido. Isso inclui também o OS-X (Apple) que também é um sistema "unix based", por exemplo. Claro que não vai encontrar um hosting oferecendo OS-X como servidor.. foi meramente um exemplo. Porpem, no ambiente de testes, o developer pode ser um usuário Apple. Aí sim teria uma relevância. (dentro do contexto da sua pergunta específico, Diego Felipe)